# Javascript math text field

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to fiddle with an some easy maths in javaascript, but I don't get it to work and I am a real beginner in js.

Basically I am just trying to use 'result1' as a variable for a second simple math, but it seems like it's not working that the id 'result' is accepted.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<input id="value1" type="text" onchange="output();" />
<span> + </span>
<input id="value2" type="text" onchange="output();" />
<span> * </span>
<input id="value3" type="text" onchange="output();" />
<p id="result1"> </p>


<span> + </span>
<input id="value5" type="text" onchange="output();" />
<p id="result2"> </p>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8">


function output(){
    var value1 = document.getElementById('value1').value;
    var value2 = document.getElementById('value2').value;
    var value3 = document.getElementById('value3').value;
    document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = (parseInt(value1) + parseInt(value2)) * parseInt(value3);
    var value4 = document.getElementById('result1').value;
    var value5 = document.getElementById('value5').value;
    document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = parseInt(value4) + parseInt(value5);
     
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8x7oq4o2/)

Comment: p has a textContent and not a value property (value is used on input elements). http://jsfiddle.net/8x7oq4o2/1/

Comment: Please post your code in this question rather than linking to another site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p` has a `textContent` and not a `value` property (`value` is used on `input` elements).

```
//var value4 = document.getElementById('result1').value; //Wrong property
var value4 = document.getElementById('result1').textContent; //Correct property
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8x7oq4o2/2/

Answer (score 1):

Use `innerHTML` to get the value of `p` tag and use `parseInt` on that value to get that as a integer then it will work as expected:

```js
function output(){
    var value1 = document.getElementById('value1').value;
    var value2 = document.getElementById('value2').value;
    var value3 = document.getElementById('value3').value;
    document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = (parseInt(value1) + parseInt(value2)) * parseInt(value3);
    var value4 = document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML;
    var value5 = document.getElementById('value5').value;
    document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = parseInt(value4) + parseInt(value5);
     
}
```

```html
<input id="value1" type="text" onchange="output();" />
<span> + </span>
<input id="value2" type="text" onchange="output();" />
<span> * </span>
<input id="value3" type="text" onchange="output();" />
<p id="result1"> </p>


<span> + </span>
<input id="value5" type="text" onchange="output();" />
<p id="result2"> </p>
```

Comment: Well, I do not think that parseInt() twice is really necessary here, since it is already there at the last line (document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML).

Comment: @Lain nice point. Thanks for the notice

Answer (score 0):

You should use textContent on " value4 "

```js
function output(){
    var value1 = document.getElementById('value1').value;
    var value2 = document.getElementById('value2').value;
    var value3 = document.getElementById('value3').value;
    document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = (parseInt(value1) + parseInt(value2)) * parseInt(value3);
    var value4 = document.getElementById('result1').textContent;
    var value5 = document.getElementById('value5').value;
    document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = parseInt(value4) + parseInt(value5);
     
}
```

```html
<input id="value1" type="text" onchange="output();" />
<span> + </span>
<input id="value2" type="text" onchange="output();" />
<span> * </span>
<input id="value3" type="text" onchange="output();" />
<p id="result1"> </p>


<span> + </span>
<input id="value5" type="text" onchange="output();" />
<p id="result2"> </p>
```

Comment: Thanks guys, all or your suggestions were helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Calc value4 before seting its value to result1:

```
var value4 = (parseInt(value1) + parseInt(value2)) * parseInt(value3);
document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = value4;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<input id="value1" type="text" onchange="output();" />
<span> + </span>
<input id="value2" type="text" onchange="output();" />
<span> * </span>
<input id="value3" type="text" onchange="output();" />
<p id="result1"> </p>


<span> + </span>
<input id="value5" type="text" onchange="output();" />
<p id="result2"> </p>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8">


function output(){
    var value1 = document.getElementById('value1').value;
    var value2 = document.getElementById('value2').value;
    var value3 = document.getElementById('value3').value;
    
    // changes are in below 2 lines
    var value4 = (parseInt(value1) + parseInt(value2)) * parseInt(value3);
    document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = value4;
    
    var value5 = document.getElementById('value5').value;
    document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = parseInt(value4) + parseInt(value5);
     
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```